# Overloading endl compilation issue in GNU g++ 4.9.2

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, ostream, endl

I'm having problem in compilation of the following code snippet while using GNU g++ 4.9.2 (used to compile ok in g++ 2.95.3)

```
XOStream &operator<<(ostream &(*f)(ostream &))  {
        if(f == std::endl) {
                *this << "\n" << flush;
        }
        else {
                ostr << f;
        }
        return(*this);
}
```

The error is as below:

```
error: assuming cast to type 'std::basic_ostream<char>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char>&)' from overloaded function [-fpermissive]
     [exec]    if(f == std::endl) {
     [exec]                 ^
```

Please guide/help.

Comment: Note: To avoid running into this kind of problems you may write a XOStreamBuffer and attach it to the XOStream (being an almost unchanged ostream)

Comment: So, why are you not just letting `endl` do its thing?  Because you want to intercept `flush` at the `XOStream` level instead of at the `ostr` level?  You could also simplify the `else` to `return f(ostr);` directly...  I guess if it too is doing a similar hack, that won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the overload of `std::endl` with a `static_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

inline bool is_endl(std::ostream &(*f)(std::ostream &)) {
    // return (f == static_cast<std::ostream &(*)(std::ostream &)>(std::endl));
    // Even nicer (Thanks M.M)
    return (f == static_cast<decltype(f)>(std::endl));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_endl(std::endl) << '\n';
    std::cout << is_endl(std::flush) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: or `static_cast<decltype(f)>`

Answer (score 2):

[`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) is a function template, you need to specify the template arguments. Because you're using [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) (i.e. `basic_ostream<char>`) you could

```
if (f == endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>)
```